# Delete from adls gen 2 Delta files fails with error

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I have requirement where I am deleting duplicate records from delta file using databricks sql. Below is my query

```
%sql
delete from delta.`adls_delta_file_path` where code = 'XYZ '
```

but it gives below error

com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:529) at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:527) at com.privacera.spark.agent.bV.a(bV.java) at com.privacera.spark.agent.bV.a(bV.java) at com.privacera.spark.agent.bc.a(bc.java) at com.privacera.spark.agent.bc.apply(bc.java) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreach(TreeNode.scala:252) at com.privacera.spark.agent.bV.a(bV.java) at com.privacera.spark.base.interceptor.c.b(c.java) at com.privacera.spark.base.interceptor.c.a(c.java) at com.privacera.spark.agent.n.a(n.java) at com.privacera.spark.agent.n.apply(n.java) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$3(RuleExecutor.scala:221) at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:221) at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126) at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:218) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:210) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:210) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:188) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:109) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:188) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$optimizedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:112) at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:134) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:180) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:180) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:109) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:109) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertOptimized(QueryExecution.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:139) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:136) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$simpleString$2(QueryExecution.scala:199) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExplainUtils$.processPlan(ExplainUtils.scala:115) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.simpleString(QueryExecution.scala:199) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:260) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainStringLocal(QueryExecution.scala:226) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:123) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:273) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:223) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3823) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:235) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:104) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:101) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:689) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:684) at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.$anonfun$executeSql$1(SQLDriverLocal.scala:91) at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392) at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238) at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231) at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:37) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:145) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$11(DriverLocal.scala:529) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266) at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:506) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:611) at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:603) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommandAndGetError(DriverWrapper.scala:522) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:557) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:130) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:145) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$11(DriverLocal.scala:529) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266) at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305) at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:506) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:611) at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:603) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommandAndGetError(DriverWrapper.scala:522) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:557) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370) at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any suggestion here .

Comment: Can you please provide additional information about the delta table (schema, sample data)

Answer (score 0):

> com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptionsSQLExecutionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:529)

And firstly, convert your delta file to delta table in databricks and enable the support for SQL commands by [Configuring SparkSession](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#-sql-support) then delete the duplicate records from delta table

For more understanding on conversion of file to delta table refer this document by Microsoft [Delta Lake quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/quick-start)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to cluster configuration .We have databricks cluster managed by Privecera.There are certain configuration in cluster that privecera blocks.We tried  running on cluster without privecera and it worked.Raised a request with Privecera to find out actual cause.

Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).